# Facebook Android notification broadcast receiver

Tags: android, facebook, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Is there any way to listen to Facebook notifications in a custom application? e.g. in case of SMS, I can receive a text in a broadcast receiver and show a custom message. If my Facebook account is logged in is there anyway to listen for notifications?